# how to increase internalstorage on an Android devise

Tags: browser

I am using WHAM! WG40 mobile. It's internal storage is only 120mb. How can I increase it's internal storage.

Answer (score 0):

You can get and SD card purchased and insert it over the SD card slot it will increase your device storage!

Answer (score 0):

You can use ROM (Read only memory) as your internal storage. For this you need to have your phone "rooted". Means root your phone then install ES File Explorer and grand super user permission to ES File Explorer then you can set your ROM or your sd card as default installation memory. Mean you can use your sd card and rom as phone memory(Internal storage).